# Should I choose "come out of the room" or "come out from the room"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

context:

> 1. You just come out of the room.
> 2. You just come out from the room.

I am confused with "come out of" and the "come out from".

Comment: Both versions are fine. Idiomatically, [***He just came out of nowhere*** is far more common than ***He just came out from nowhere***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=just+came+out+of+nowhere%2Cjust+came+out+from+nowhere%2Cjust+came+from+nowhere&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjust%20came%20out%20of%20nowhere%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjust%20came%20from%20nowhere%3B%2Cc0), but you'll also see from that link that ***He just came from nowhere*** (without ***out***) is also common.

Comment: In what context? "out of the room" simply means that. "out from the room" implies that you went somewhere (You come out from the room and went into the kitchen). Using *just* also points to some context not in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are grammatically correct, but "out of" sounds good to my American ear.